# How to patch AMD GPU drivers?

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, monitor, amdgpu, overclocking

I want to change the refresh rate of my monitor (overclock it), but when I do this, the image on the display starts to be pixelated. There is driver patcher for windows, but it can't find location of the driver. I use RX560 with custom BIOS, so the default driver conflicts with the changed refresh rate. Is it possible to fix it?